# Can I log training loss via a hook with a LinearRegressor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm quite new at TensorFlow. I'm using TF 1.8 for a 'simple' linear regression.
The output of the exercise is the set of linear weights that best fit the data, rather than a prediction model. So I would like to track and log the current minimum loss during training, along with the corresponding value of the weights.

I'm trying to use a `LinearRegressor`:

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

model = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(
    feature_columns = make_feature_cols(),
    model_dir = TRAINING_OUTDIR
)

# --------------------------------------------v
logger = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook({"loss": ???}, every_n_iter=10)
trainHooks = [logger]

model.train(
    input_fn = make_train_input_fn(df, num_epochs = nEpochs),
    hooks = trainHooks
)
```

The model doesn't seem to contain a variable for the loss.

**Can I use the `LoggingTensorHook` somehow? In which case, how do I define the loss tensor?**

I also tried implementing my own hook. Examples suggest registering the loss inside `before_run` by calling `SessionRunArgs`, but I run into the same question there.

Thanks!!

Comment: As far as I can tell this does not seem to be directly possible, looking through the source it seems that the tensors that compute the loss are not given any explicit names and are not directly referenciable from the estimator. _Maybe_ (not sure) you could access the metrics tensors, but even then that would give you metric messages for TensorBoard, not something you can log. Maybe if you wrote your own `model_fn` it would be possible, but it kinda misses the point of canned estimators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @jdehesa that `loss` is not directly available without writing a custom `model_fn`. However, with `LoggingTensorHook` you can get features estimates at every step and calculate any loss or other training metric yourself. I suggest using `formatter` to handle tensor values available to the hook. In the example below I use `LoggingTensorHook` 
 with custom `formatter` to output feature estimates and current MSE loss.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

"""prepare inputs - generate sample data"""
num_features = 5
features = ['f'+str(i) for i in range (num_features)]
X = np.random.randint(-1000,1000, (10000, num_features))
a = np.random.randint (2, 30, size = (num_features))/10
b = np.random.randint(-99, 99)/10
y = np.matmul(X, a) + b
noise = np.random.randn(*X.shape)
X = X + (noise * 1)
X.shape, y.shape, a, b
>> ((10000, 5), (10000,), array([2.1, 2. , 1.7, 0.5, 0.9]), 1.8)

""" create model """
feature_cols = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k) for k in features]  
X_dict = {features[i]:X[:,i] for i in range (num_features) }

TRAINING_OUTDIR = '.'
model = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(
    model_dir = TRAINING_OUTDIR,
    feature_columns = feature_cols)

input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    X_dict, y, batch_size=512, num_epochs=50, shuffle=True,
    queue_capacity=1000, num_threads=1)

input_fn_predict = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    X_dict, batch_size=X.shape[0], shuffle=False)

"""create hook and formatter"""
feature_var_names = [f"linear/linear_model/{f}/weights" for f in features]
hook_vars_list = ['global_step', 'linear/linear_model/bias_weights'] + feature_var_names

def hooks_formatter (tensor_dict):
    step = tensor_dict['global_step']
    a_hat = [tensor_dict[feat][0][0] for feat in feature_var_names]
    b_hat = tensor_dict['linear/linear_model/bias_weights'][0]
    y_pred = np.dot (X, np.array(a_hat).T) + b_hat
    mse_loss =  np.mean((y - y_pred)**2)   # MSE
    line = f"step:{step}; MSE_loss: {mse_loss:.4f}; bias:{b_hat:.3f};"
    for f,w in zip (features, a_hat):
        line += f" {f}:{w:.3f};"
    return line
hook1 = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(hook_vars_list, every_n_iter=10, formatter=hooks_formatter)

"""train"""
model.train(input_fn = input_fn, steps=100,hooks = [hook1])
>>>
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1 into ./model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:step:1; MSE_loss: 3183865.8670; bias:0.200; f0:0.200; f1:0.200; f2:0.200; f3:0.200; f4:0.200;
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1924836100.0, step = 1
INFO:tensorflow:step:11; MSE_loss: 1023556.4537; bias:0.359; f0:0.936; f1:0.944; f2:0.903; f3:0.521; f4:0.802;
INFO:tensorflow:step:21; MSE_loss: 468665.2052; bias:0.269; f0:1.294; f1:1.276; f2:1.202; f3:0.437; f4:0.857;
INFO:tensorflow:step:31; MSE_loss: 232310.3535; bias:0.292; f0:1.513; f1:1.491; f2:1.379; f3:0.528; f4:0.893;
INFO:tensorflow:step:41; MSE_loss: 118843.3051; bias:0.278; f0:1.671; f1:1.633; f2:1.491; f3:0.472; f4:0.898;
INFO:tensorflow:step:51; MSE_loss: 62416.4437; bias:0.272; f0:1.782; f1:1.735; f2:1.563; f3:0.505; f4:0.903;
INFO:tensorflow:step:61; MSE_loss: 32799.2320; bias:0.277; f0:1.865; f1:1.808; f2:1.611; f3:0.487; f4:0.899;
INFO:tensorflow:step:71; MSE_loss: 17619.6118; bias:0.270; f0:1.924; f1:1.861; f2:1.641; f3:0.510; f4:0.904;
INFO:tensorflow:step:81; MSE_loss: 9423.0092; bias:0.283; f0:1.970; f1:1.899; f2:1.661; f3:0.494; f4:0.900;
INFO:tensorflow:step:91; MSE_loss: 5062.2780; bias:0.285; f0:2.003; f1:1.927; f2:1.675; f3:0.503; f4:0.901;
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 100 into ./model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 1693422.1.
<tensorflow.python.estimator.canned.linear.LinearRegressor at 0x7f90a590f240>
```